# How to count the number of characters in a file (not using the len function)?

Tags: python, file

Basically, I want to be able to count the number of characters in a txt file (with user input of file name). I can get it to display how many lines are in the file, but not how many characters. I am not using the len function and this is what I have:

```
def length(n):
    value = 0
    for char in n:
        value += 1
return value
filename = input('Enter the name of the file: ')
f = open(filename)
for data in f:
    data = length(f)
    print(data)
```

Comment: Why are you avoiding `len` function? Homework?

Comment: `os.path.getsize("/path/to/file")`? Depending on the definition of "character".

Comment: @freakish: Since this is Python 3, and he's opening the file in text mode, I think the definition of "character" is probably "Unicode character", not "encoded byte".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is sum the number of characters in each line (`data`):

```
total = 0
for line in f:
    data = length(line)
    total += data
print(total)
```

Comment: Excellent thanks everyone! I am new to python and I appreciate the explanations from you guys! Its difficult to go from VB to Python, so the syntax gets really confusing to me.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems.

First, for each line in the file, you're passing `f` itself—that is, a sequence of lines—to `length`. That's why it's printing the number of lines in the file. The length of that sequence of lines is the number of lines in the file.

To fix this, you want to pass each line, `data`—that is, a sequence of characters. So:

```
for data in f:
    print length(data)
```

---

Next, while that will properly calculate the length of *each* line, you have to add them all up to get the length of the whole file. So:

```
total_length = 0
for data in f:
    total_length += length(data)
print(total_length)
```

---

However, there's another way to tackle this that's a lot simpler. If you `read()` the file, you will get one giant string, instead of a sequence of separate lines. So you can just call `length` once:

```
data = f.read()
print(length(data))
```

The problem with this is that you have to have enough memory to store the whole file at once. Sometimes that's not appropriate. But sometimes it is.

Comment: No love for `sum`? Maybe `sum(map(length, f))` is just too much to explain in one go, or I guess someone not using `len` probably isn't using `sum` either ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, I was assuming that if he's not allowed to use `len` he's not allowed to use `sum`. Of course you could write your own `sum_numbers` function the same way he wrote his own `length` function, but that's even more to explain. And then I'd also have to write and explain a comprehension or `map` call. It didn't seem worth it, when `length(f.read())` is an even simpler simplification. But it's worth having your comment as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over a file (opened in text mode) you are iterating over its lines.
`for data in f:` could be rewritten as `for line in f:` and it is easier to see what it is doing.

Your length function looks like it should work but you are *sending* the open file to it instead of each line.